# assembly macro for adding two 64bit numbers on a 32bit machine

Tags: assembly, macros, x86, nasm, x86-16

I need to write a macro for adding 2 64bit on a 32bit machine.

 One way I thought about is as follows:

```
%macro add_double 2
mov edx, %1
add %2,edx
mov edx,%1
shl edx,31
mov eax,%2
shl eax,31
add eax,edx
add %2,eax
%endmacro
```

will this even work? 
also I was wondering... there is a simple way of doing it using [] 
but is it possible doing [%1] for example in a macro? I am new to assembly so I don't know.

Comment: Where are these two 64-bit values located? In two 32-bit register pairs? If so, wouldn't your macro need 4 arguments? Anyway, your current implementation doesn't look correct to me. I didn't try running it, but it looks like if you gave 1 and 0 as arguments you'd get 0x80000001 as the result.

Comment: `adc` is specifically invented for this.

Answer (score 2):

To add numbers in chunks of 32 bit you have to use the fact that `add` set the `CF`. So the low 32 bits are added as normal, the high ones are added with `adc` which include the carry flag in the addition.

These macros should do

```
%macro add_double 4
mov eax, %1
mov edx, %2
add eax, %3
adc edx, %4
%endmacro

%macro add_doublev 2
mov eax, DWORD [%1]
mov edx, DWORD [%1+04h]
add eax, DWORD [%2]
adc edx, DWORD [%2+04h]
%endmacro
```

The `add_double` takes 4 32 bits numbers, the first are the low 32 bits of the first number, the second the 32 high bits. The other two number are the same but for the second number. To add `0xff00000000` to `0x8800000000` use it as `add_double 0, 0ffh, 0, 88h`.
The `add_doublev` takes 2 addresses from which to fetch the two 64 bits numbers (in little endian). Use it as

```
num1 dd 0, 0ffh
num2 dd 0, 088h

add_doublev num1, num2
```

Both macros compute the result in `EDX:EAX`, meaning that `EDX` holds the upper 32 bits and `EAX` the lower 32 bits.